# man pages for c variable types

Tags: c, unix, manpage

Are there any Unix `man` pages or similar standardized reference for variable type declarations (in c)?

For example, if I want details on the `float` variable type and different ways to declare it, is there a standardized reference in Unix?  The compiler man pages? Or is an online reference or book on C required?

I just saw `float power=2.345f` when reading [Learn C the Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/), was wondering what the `f` means, and quickly learned that `man 3 float` and `man float` do not produce anything, and even `man -k float`  does not seem to show any relevant results.

So, where to look for definitive answers about c variable types and their declarations, preferably retrievable on the OS without internet access?

Comment: You need reference to the language, not an OS. Look for the standard specification docs.

Comment: The `f` suffix on a floating-point number makes it a `float` literal, rather than a `double` (which is the type of non-suffixed floating-point literals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [**C11 standard**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). On wikipedia, you will find referencess to all standards, including the older ones. Do not worry (too much) about them being draft; that is mustly due to ortographic corrections, etc. The final versions will cost money, so most here (and elsewhere) use the drafts.

Linux man pages for C functions are mostly a courtesy and cover POSIX aspects. You should not rely they exist or complain they do not.

If you have problems reading the standard, just get a good book.

Comment: Looks great and definitive indeed, any comments on the difference or relative strengths of the standard compared to the gnu manual posted below

Comment: @hilcharge Sorry, I do not understand your second part. Where "below"?

Comment: Below your answer, sorry, ie the gnu manual mentioned by Jeremy.

Comment: @hilcharge: You really ask me to detail you the differences of POSIX vs C? Sorry, deep consuling will be billed extra:-}

Comment: Thanks for understanding, I'd had to search myself! Try the web (e.g. wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a manual page for C/C++. I would probably download a manual like this for offline viewing: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/index.html